# Microsoft Graph APIs permissions differ between the documentation and what is available under Azure Portal

Tags: azure, graph, portal

I would like to get the list of a user's devices via the Microsoft Graph API (AAD sign-in).

However the permissions listed here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_registereddevices differ from what is actually available under Microsoft Graph permissions (App registration - Azure portal).

Even by granting all permissions in the portal I still get 403 (Forbidden) when trying to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/registeredDevices from my application.

Note: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/registeredDevices works using the Graph Explorer

Note: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me works from my application

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share the request id? It's returned in the response headers from Microsoft graph.